# CSS no border width

Tags: css, border

I'm making a simple tabbed interface out of divs. Can someone offer a way of making a div have a bottom border width of 0px, otherwise I get a 1px gap between the tab div and the tab content. Do I use `border-left`, `border-right` and `border-top` instead of `border` and `border-bottom: 0px;`?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
```

Sets all to 1px and then overrides the bottom to 0px.

Also valid is the shorthand:

```
border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
```

Where the third value is the bottom width (top, right, bottom, left)

Comment: It's slicker to do `border: 1px solid red` and then `border-bottom: 0`.

Comment: My bad... I use `border: 1px solid red` every day :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use border it goes clockwise, and repeats the non specified parts on the mirror.

So you want: border-width: blah blah 0px blah

Also, are you sure it's the border? It could also be the padding or margin (<- more likely).

Answer (score 0):

When you have two DIV's as siblings, like so:

```
<div> One </div>
<div> Two </div>
```

then, by default, there is no space between them.

**Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/wm7GA/

Answer (score 0):

Use [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) as first included css file.

Comment: What does CSS reset have to do with anything?

Comment: Default css shouldn't have any margin, padding or border between divs, this maybe can fix it by zeroing them.